# Use @Where annotation on external entity in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I would like to use @Where annotation at entity level but my entity come from an external dependency ...

Do you know how i can achieve that ?

Thanks

Comment: Theoretically you could map the entity with XML because XML would override annotations. But I don't know if this is a good idea. Why do you want to change the entity?

Comment: I want to add @Where annotation so i don't have to rewrite all my repo methods to add " WHERE x = TRUE" in every projects ...

Comment: As I said you could use XML